# Change NEXT button position of Primefaces WIZARD component

Tags: java, css, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there any option to change the position of NEXT button of Primefaces WIZARD component?
My wizard started with the following.

```
<p:wizard flowListener="#{employeeRepositoryImpl.handleFlow}"
showNavBar="true" widgetVar="scheduler" showStepStatus="false">
</p:wizard>
```

Comment: No sure that he needs to post any code at all... as far as a I know there is only one relevant NEXT button in the Primefaces WIZARD component.... , so the Question if fine... no need to -1 it at all...

Answer (score 3):

In case css fits you well you can always do some thing like this:

```
<h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            jQuery('[id$="_next"]').css('right', 200) ;
        });
    </script>
</h:head>
```

instead of right you can use left , top ... etc , you also can mix couple of them together...

b.t.w , `jQuery('[id$="_next"]')` is a selector that finds the next button in the page

Comment: I have changed the css file like `.ui-wizard-nav-next {
    float: left;
}`, and now it is fine.

Comment: which version of primefaces do u use?

Comment: Primefaces-3.0.M3. Other latest versions got some issues with Google Cloud SQL.